# Placing array of equidistant points along a line in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following figure

[image]

generated by the code below.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (CTRL)     at ($(0,0)$) ;

  \node[draw, black, thick, ellipse,
  minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2cm,
  fill=yellow!15,name=ctrl,
  name path=ctrl] at (CTRL) {Control};

  \gettikzxy{(ctrl.south)}{\csx}{\csy}
  \gettikzxy{(ctrl.north)}{\cnx}{\cny}
  \fill[blue] (\csx, \csy) circle (2pt);
  \fill[blue] (\cnx, \cny) circle (2pt);

  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to add a sequence of points to the ellipse from top to bottom as shown below. (ideally the number of points should be configurable via a parameter). So the result I want is something like this. How do I do it?

[image]

I guess what I am looking for is something equivalent to an [numpy linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)  command, but performing math inside TikZ code seems very verbose to put it mildly. I am using pdflatex, but I would also be interested in a solution using lualatex if that makes this simpler.

Comment: You can do `($(ctrl.south)!<factor>!(ctrl.north)$)` which specified a point that is `<factor>` between south and north. `<factor>` = .5 is halfway between them. 0 is at the first, 1 and the second coordinate. You can do that in a loop. The same is possible without `calc` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `\foreach` loop and `calc`'s coordinate calculation you can do the following pretty easily.

The commented path is the same using nodes placed along the path. (With a `pic` we could also do the same with complex drawings that can't be nodes.)

This can be automated more depending on where and how you need it.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (CTRL)     at (0,0);

\node[draw, black, thick, ellipse,
minimum height=3cm, minimum width=2cm,
fill=yellow!15,name=ctrl] at (CTRL) {Control};

\foreach \i in {0, ..., 7}
  \fill[blue] ($(ctrl.south)!\i/7!(ctrl.north)$) circle[radius=2pt];

%\path (ctrl.south) -- (ctrl.north)
%  node foreach \i in {0, ..., 7}
%    [circle, minimum size=4pt, inner sep=+0pt, fill=blue, pos=\i/7]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]